sqlalchemy - `validates` on a Relationship does not emit on assignment event
Consider the following using sqlalchemy:
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

class DeviceTestResult:
    __tablename__ = "device_test"

    passed: bool = mapped_column(default=False, init=False)
    failure_modes: Mapped[list['FailureMode']] = relationship(default_factory=list, back_populates='test')

    @validates('failure_modes')
    def validate_failure_modes(self, key, failure_mode):
        """
        Validator for failure modes. When attribute is changed, updates passed to be false if there are any fails.
        """
        currently_passes = all([fm.passed for fm in self.failure_modes])
        self.passed = all([fm for fm in [currently_passes, failure_mode.passed]])
        return failure_mode


class FailureMode:
    __tablename__ = "failure_mode"
    
    passed: bool = mapped_column()
    test: Mapped['DeviceTestResult'] = relationship(back_populates='failure_modes', default=None)
    completed_at: datetime = mapped_column(insert_default=datetime.now(), default=datetime.now())

    @validates('passed')
    def validate_test(self, key, passed):
        """
        validator for passed. Updates associated test object status
        """
        if self.test:
            currently_passes = all([fm.passed for fm in self.test.failure_modes])
            self.test._passed = all([fm for fm in [currently_passes, passed]])
        return passed

# Case 1 - append, emits validate_failure_modes
device_test = DeviceTest()
failure_mode = FailureMode()
device.failure_modes.append(failure_mode)

# Case 2 - assignment, does not emit validate_failure_modes
device.failure_modes = [failure_mode]

validate_failure_modes is emitted in case 1, but not in case 2.
How can I get validation in case 2? If that's not possible, how can I restrict a user from setting the attribute using assignment, so that they can only modify via appending?
I've experimented with using sqlalchemy descriptors & hybrids but haven't gotten it to work.

Also being discussed on GitHub here

The issue was not with the validator not running on every item on the list (it was) - it has to do with the order in which validation is done.
To give some context, I've got a device_test object, and a failure_mode object. device_test can have many different failure modes, and if a failure_mode is added that does not pass, device_test also should not pass.
class DeviceTestResult:
tablename = "device_test"
count = 0
passed: bool = mapped_column(default=False, init=False)
failure_modes: Mapped[list["FailureMode"]] = relationship(
    default_factory=list, back_populates="tests"
)

idx: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
    primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, init=False, sort_order=-1
)

@validates("failure_modes")
def validate_failure_modes(self, key, failure_mode):
    """
    Validator for failure modes. When attribute is changed, updates passed to be false if there are any fails.
    """
    self.count += 1
    currently_passes = all([fm.passed for fm in self.failure_modes])
    self.passed = currently_passes and failure_mode.passed
    return failure_mode

@__reg.mapped_as_dataclass
class FailureMode:
tablename = "failure_mode"
passed: bool = mapped_column()
tests: Mapped["DeviceTestResult"] = relationship(
    back_populates="failure_modes", default=None
)

idx: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
    primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, init=False, sort_order=-1
)
test_idx: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("device_test.idx"), init=False)

When a list is assigned to DeviceTestResult.failure_modes, what I expected to happen was:
An individual FailureMode is validated by validate_failure_mode
The FailureMode is added to DeviceTestResult.failure_modes

What happens instead is that each individual FailureMode is validated, and then the assignment is completed.
To solve my issue, I changed DeviceTestResult.passed to a read only property using hybrid_properties that reads the value of DeviceTestResult.failure_modes directly.
